# What is the meaning of "of interest to anyone" in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "of interest to anyone" in the following sentences?

> This book is brimming with up-to-date application circuits, valuable design tips, and in-depth coverage of the latest techniques to simplify op amp circuit designs, and improve their performance. As an added bonus, a selection on the history of op amp development provides an extensive and expertly researched overview, **of interest to anyone** involved in this important area of electronics.

Does "of interest to anyone" mean "the history of op amp development is of interest to anyone"?

Or does "of interest to anyone" mean "researched overview is of interest to anyone"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overview.  This is both because its position, closest to the prepositional phrase, and because the overview is the bonus the book provides, and therefore what is being praised